# Eclipse Plugin: Adding Custom Suggestion in Default Code Completion Pop-up window

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, code-completion, content-assist

I'm making an eclipse plugin that requires to add some custom suggestions in the default eclipse pop-up window. For doing so, I came to know from [eclipse doc](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaCompletionProposalComputer.html&resultof=%22%7Bexpression%7D%22%20%22express%22%20) that I have to implement the `IJavaCompletionProposalComputer` to participate in content assist process . Accordingly, I tried the below implementation found in [github](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/java/HippieProposalComputer.java). I understand that it overrides the `computeCompletionProposals()` method that computes suggestions and returns as `ICompletionProposal` List. But I failed to find what to do for **adding my custom suggestions in the default pop-up window.**

Any idea how I can do that?

```
package zzz.handlers;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposal;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ICompletionProposal;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.IContextInformation;
import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HippieProposalProcessor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.ContentAssistInvocationContext;
import org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.IJavaCompletionProposalComputer;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Our sample handler extends AbstractHandler, an IHandler base class.
 * @see org.eclipse.core.commands.IHandler
 * @see org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler
 */
/**
 * A computer wrapper for the hippie processor.
 *
 * @since 3.2
 */
public final class HippieProposalComputer implements IJavaCompletionProposalComputer {
    /** The wrapped processor. */
    private final HippieProposalProcessor fProcessor= new HippieProposalProcessor();

    /**
     * Default ctor to make it instantiatable via the extension mechanism.
     */
    public HippieProposalComputer() {
    }

    /*
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ICompletionProposalComputer#computeCompletionProposals(org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.TextContentAssistInvocationContext, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)
     */
    @Override
    public List<ICompletionProposal> computeCompletionProposals(ContentAssistInvocationContext context, IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        return Arrays.asList(fProcessor.computeCompletionProposals(context.getViewer(), context.getInvocationOffset()));
    }

    /*
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ICompletionProposalComputer#computeContextInformation(org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.TextContentAssistInvocationContext, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)
     */
    @Override
    public List<IContextInformation> computeContextInformation(ContentAssistInvocationContext context, IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        return Arrays.asList(fProcessor.computeContextInformation(context.getViewer(), context.getInvocationOffset()));
    }

    /*
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ICompletionProposalComputer#getErrorMessage()
     */
    @Override
    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return fProcessor.getErrorMessage();
    }

    /*
     * @see org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.IJavaCompletionProposalComputer#sessionStarted()
     */
    @Override
    public void sessionStarted() {
    }

    /*
     * @see org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.IJavaCompletionProposalComputer#sessionEnded()
     */
    @Override
    public void sessionEnded() {
    }
}
```

My `plugin.xml` is as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

 <extension point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer"
       id="WordCompletionProposalComputer"
       name="Word Completion Proposal Computer">
       <javaCompletionProposalComputer
          class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.HippieProposalComputer"
          categoryId="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.textual_proposals">
          <partition type="__java_javadoc"/>
       </javaCompletionProposalComputer>
     </extension>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            name="Sample Category"
            id="zadawdaw.commands.category">
      </category>
      <command
            name="Sample Command"
            categoryId="zadawdaw.commands.category"
            id="zadawdaw.commands.sampleCommand">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            commandId="zadawdaw.commands.sampleCommand"
            class="zadawdaw.handlers.SampleHandler">
      </handler>
   </extension>

   <extension point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer"
   id="textual_proposals"
   name="Text Proposals">
   <proposalCategory icon="icons/wordcompletions.png"/>
 </extension>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               label="Sample Menu"
               mnemonic="M"
               id="zadawdaw.menus.sampleMenu">
            <command
                  commandId="zadawdaw.commands.sampleCommand"
                  mnemonic="S"
                  id="zadawdaw.menus.sampleCommand">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
         <toolbar
               id="zadawdaw.toolbars.sampleToolbar">
            <command
                  commandId="zadawdaw.commands.sampleCommand"
                  icon="icons/sample.png"
                  tooltip="Say hello world"
                  id="zadawdaw.toolbars.sampleCommand">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Comment: Have you added the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer` extension point for this to your plugin.xml? Is the code being called?

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, i've added `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer` extension point in `plugin.xml`. I'm not sure whether it's being called or not. How can i check that?

Comment: Use a debugger or just print something in the different methods.

Comment: @greg-449... looks like it is not being called. It gives me the following error when testing...
[https://pastebin.com/0W2zEyhe](https://pastebin.com/0W2zEyhe)

Comment: @greg-449 Now I've made the code being called. Can you please tell me How I can get the desired out as my question states? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this extension point.

Comment: Can you also post the plugin.xml section contributing it? Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: zzz.handlers.HippieProposalComputer cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.commands.IHandler implies you're using the wrong one.

Comment: @nitind... Deeply sorry for late reply. I've added my `plugin.xml` file. Can you please take a look?

Comment: S.t. doesn't look consistent. Javadoc of your proposal computer speaks of extending `AbstractHandler`, but the code actually doesn't. The stack trace signals that the proposal computer is registered in `plugin.xml` as an `IHandler`, but the shown `plugin.xml` doesn't. Either another plugin is involved, which you don't show here, or the snippets shown are not precisely what you have tested? As one way to reduce confusion I suggest you remove everything relating to your Sample Command and the corresponding `IHandler` from `plugin.xml`.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann Yes, you're right. I've created a "Hello World" Template project and added the extension point with the already existed extension point. I called this `HippieProposalComputer` by creating an object of it in `SampleHandle.java`, a file that was generated when creating "Hello World" template project. Am I doing wrong? I just want to access the code-completion pop-up window and add some string to it as code suggestion. Can you please help?

Comment: When you register your class via an extension point, you don't manually instantiate it, just wait until the framework will instantiate it and call methods on it. If you still get the CCE, you may want to remove all declarations relating to handlers in your `plugin.xml`. They're not needed for installing your proposal computer.

Comment: Do you intend to add your proposals only when completion is invoked in javadoc regions (see the `<partition>` element)?

Comment: @StephanHerrmann I intend to make a plugin that adds proposals(some strings) in the completion pop-up window when `ctrl+space` is pressed while writing code in eclipse editor. I don't have good knowledge in `<partition>` element. Just copied it from [eclipse doc](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaCompletionProposalComputer.html&resultof=%22%7Bexpression%7D%22%20%22express%22%20) Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the main mistake so far is restricting the proposal provider to the partition type `__java_javadoc`.

You were already looking (almost?) in the [right place](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaCompletionProposalComputer.html&cp=3_1_1_27) - look for `type`. Please see that this definition also refers to [IJavaPartitions](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fui%2Ftext%2FIJavaPartitions.html). In terse words, partitions refer to segments of text in an editor. The linked interface lists the possible constants together with a short description.

If you want completions to be proposed while editing Java code, try `IJavaPartitions.JAVA_PARTITIONING`.